# How can I find a specific item from a list with only 1/2 values

Tags: python

I have a list that looks like the following: `list1 = [(clients_socket1, clients_username1, clients_ip1), (clients_socket2, clients_username2, clients_ip2)]`.
The reason I am asking this is because I am trying to find a more optimized way of finding a item in a list with just the `clients_username` for example.

I currently have:

```
match = False
username = clients_username1
 for item in list1:
     if username == user[1]:
         match = True
 if match:
# Do stuff here
```

I was wondering if there was a better way to do this.

Comment: `break` once a match is found, or keep a `dict` of the socket, username, ip tuples with the keys being the username.

Comment: Need more information... Are the names guaranteed to be unique? Then use a dictionary. If not, then what do you plan to do on duplicates? Only return the first?

Comment: @OneCricketeer This code is for when a new client connects then it checks if they are trying to connect with a username that is already registered in the system. If it finds an already existing username then it tells the client to disconnect and pick a new username. The client can then reconnect with a different username and the process repeats.

Comment: Thanks, thats not really the information I meant, though. Two users cannot have the same username in that list?

Comment: Rather than storing an in-memory list, could you use a database instead?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can optimize the code by `break`ing out of the loop after you find a match:

```
match = False
username = clients_username1
 for item in list1:
     if username == user[1]:
         match = True
         break # <-- add this
 if match:
# Do stuff here
```

---

Another option is using the `any` [built-in function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any)

---

The final and most efficient option is converting your data-structure into a `dict` or a `set` to have O(1) membership testing, but this will only work if usernames are guaranteed to be unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `dict` to index the list. Then the lookup is

```
list1_index_by_name = {item[1]:item for item in list1}
username = client_username1
item = list1_index_by_name.get(username, None):
if item is not None:
    do_stuff_here()
```

This is *slower* in this particular example because you only use the index once. But assuming you do this more often, and the list is more than a few items, it will eventually be more efficient than a brute-force lookup. You will also need to maintain the index - adding and removing items as the list changes.